# Why are there multiple verbs in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, verbs

> You will have classes with the rest of your
> House, sleep in your House dormitory, and spend free
> time in your House common room.

This is from Harry Potter. I think "have", "sleep" and "spend" are verbs in this sentence, while I don't understand how does "sleep" exists here as a verb without a conjunction? I guess that means it's also not a participle.

Answer (score 1):

> You will have classes with the rest of your House, sleep in your House dormitory, and spend free time in your House common room.

This is a three-element list, and in lists, you only put a conjunction before the last element.

The author could have written this:

> You will have classes ..., you will sleep ..., and you will spend ....

However, when the subject (you) is the same for each element of the list, we don’t need to repeat it. We can do the same with verbs, even a helping verb (will) attached to different main verbs (have, sleep, spend).

Comment: Thank you Stephen! Do you mean that this is not limited to three-element? As long as it's a list then it's okay to use only one conjunction?

Comment: @user403214 It works for any length of list.